# Parse pandas series with a list of dicts into new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas series containing a list of dictionaries. I'd like to parse the contents of the dicts with some condition and store the results into new columns.

Here's some data to work with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [[{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150},
                         {'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 90}],
                        [{'br': 1, 'ba': 1, 'r': 100},
                         {'ba': 1, 'r': 80},
                         {'br': 2, 'ba': 1, 'r': 150}]],

                   'id': ['xxas', 'yxas'],

                   'name': [A, B]

                 })
```

I'd like to parse the contents of each dictionary with some conditional logic. Check for each dicts in the list and name columns as keys `br` and `ba`. Get the `value` of `r` `key` as assign as column value. If key is not found, `br` in this example, assign `0` as the value. Expected output:

```
id     br  ba  r     name
xxas   1   0   100   A
xxas   0   1   80    A
xxas   2   1   150   A
xxas   1   1   90    A
yxas   1   1   100   B
yxas   0   1   80    B
yxas   2   1   150   B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.concat([df.pop("d").explode().apply(pd.Series).fillna(0), df], axis=1)
print(df[["id", "br", "ba", "r", "name"]].astype(int, errors="ignore"))
```

Prints:

```
     id  br  ba    r name
0  xxas   1   1  100    A
0  xxas   0   1   80    A
0  xxas   2   1  150    A
0  xxas   1   1   90    A
1  yxas   1   1  100    B
1  yxas   0   1   80    B
1  yxas   2   1  150    B
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode` approach as a pipeline:

```
df2 = (df
 .explode('d', ignore_index=True)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.drop(columns='d')
                  .join(d['d'].apply(pd.Series)
                              .fillna(0, downcast='infer')))
 )
```

Output:

```
     id name  br  ba    r
0  xxas    A   1   1  100
1  xxas    A   0   1   80
2  xxas    A   2   1  150
3  xxas    A   1   1   90
4  yxas    B   1   1  100
5  yxas    B   0   1   80
6  yxas    B   2   1  150
```

Alternatively using `concat` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
df2 = (pd
 .concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v)
          for k,v in df['d'].iteritems()})
 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
 .droplevel(1)
 .join(df.drop(columns='d'))
 )
```

Output:

```
   br  ba    r    id name
0   1   1  100  xxas    A
0   0   1   80  xxas    A
0   2   1  150  xxas    A
0   1   1   90  xxas    A
1   1   1  100  yxas    B
1   0   1   80  yxas    B
1   2   1  150  yxas    B
```